# Submit button not working in Chrome but working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hi the logout button is not working in chrome. It is working fine in Firefox. However if I press F12 and keep the developer console open then the button works. The button also works when I press enter. I'm confused. Here is my code.

HTML Code:

```
<form name="logoutform" method="post" onsubmit="logoutConfirmation()" action="" >
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" id="logoutbutton" name="userlogout" ><br>
    </form>
```

JS Code:

```
function logoutConfirmation()
 {
alert("Thank you. Have a nice day!");
 }
```

PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['userlogout']))
    {
        setcookie('user_name', '');
        setcookie('user_id', '');
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
```

Comment: Where is your action Tag containing something like myfile.php?

Comment: Hi the PHP function is in the same page. Its not in a different page.

Comment: Nevermind!  Then use this file name!

Comment: DO you think the problem is with the PHP function? As I mentioned it works fine is I navigate using tab and press enter.

Comment: I think the problem is `action=""`. Either you try to accept answers and try to correct this or be unlucky. If you correct this and it works not yet, you could complain about that.

Comment: @Sebi2020 I apologize if my comment was offensive. I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: So if you click the button, and the developer console is closed, the alert don't show or is the form not submitted?

Comment: The form is not submitted.

Comment: Have executed your code in chrome with action set to `action="selffile.php"` and it works like a charme... don't know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Define the action php file in your form like;

```
<form name="logoutform" method="post" onsubmit="logoutConfirmation()" action="yourfile.php" >
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" id="logoutbutton" name="userlogout" ><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi the PHP function is in the same page. Its not in a different page.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set action. It's not submitted.

Try something like this if your file is named "test.php":

```
<?php
echo <<<STR
<html>
<head>
<script>
// your script
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="logoutForm" onsubmit="logoutConfirmation();" action="test.php">
    <input type="submit" name="userlogout" value="Logout" id="logoutButton">
</form>
</body>
</html>
STR;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP script is in the same file then you don't even need `action=""`.

Just do this:

```
<form name="logoutform" method="post" onsubmit="logoutConfirmation()">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" id="logoutbutton" name="userlogout" ><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is quite old. But if anyone has same chrome issue and landed here. Try these. I checked in multiple forums and nothing seems to work. So i started from scratch, the basic form element and try submitting and then add one element at a time.

```
<form action="file" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My issue was adding the php code in the action attribute. this was causing the submit button to not work in chrome.

```
// Do not add php code in your action. This will not work.
<form action="file.php?pg=<?php echo $page; ?>" method="POST">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Instead i included as a hidden element and it worked.

```
<form action="file.php" method="POST">
    ...
    <input type="hidden" name="pg" value="<?php echo $pg?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```